# Java Threads keep accumulating

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm currently trying to understand what is going on with my Java Application, below is the scenario.

1 - Application Start (Steady at 259-260 Threads)

2 - Some time goes by (Not a fixed length, sometimes it's 12 hours, others 2 minutes)

3 - Something happens, but no errors are thrown, no specific threads stop working

4 - New threads start to stack up, I create a new thread every 0.7 seconds or so, it's fired from an event. (Normally they are processed and automatically cleaned in less than one second) At this point, we can easily see the threads number going up, and they never stop. (Last log reached 1170 Threads before manual shutdown).

5 - From the point where the threads start to stack up, half of the application stops working, new threads are still fired but not processed at all.

I would like to know what COULD cause a Garbage Collector stop/break, maybe the main thread being locked? Maybe a JVM error? During this whole process, the GC is never touched directly, it keeps working as it is supposed to, until that "thing" happens.

> If you ask me, what is that "thing", I don't really know, debug shows everything flowing fine except the fact that the new threads are not FULLY parsed. (It reaches the debug code but the rest?)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is this a GC problem?  Why isn't this a "you've created a lot of threads as opposed to using a ThreadPool" problem?

Comment: I'm not saying it's a GC problem, I'm asking what COULD cause a gc stop, so that I know where to look for the cause.

Comment: Let's be explicit here then.  Are you creating these threads manually or are you actually using a thread pool?

Comment: Manually, using Lambda.

Comment: When it is in the bad state, trigger a thread dump and see what the threads are doing. And/or attach jvisualvm and see what is going on. If you need help interpreting the results, edit more information into your question.

Comment: I have deployed a patch using fixed ThreadPools, going to see if that works (may take up to 24 hours), if it does I'm posting an answer and closing this.

Comment: A thread in java is executed by a single CPU, if more threads are available then CPUs are available, they are scheduled for their execution. If plenty of threads are spawned scheduling those threads may take up some time which also slows down the general application execution. But as you asked about GC stops: according to [this blogpost](https://plumbr.eu/blog/garbage-collection/minor-gc-vs-major-gc-vs-full-gc) GC makes "stop-the-world" pauses not only on full GC cycles but also on minor cycles. This is notable if memory runs short as the GC will try to clean up space more often

Comment: We could get back to the original comment question, which I think is central. On what basis have you decided that this is a "GC has stopped" problem? You seem to have decided that it is, and you want to know "what could cause that" so that you "know where to look for the problem". As far as anyone helping you is concerned, you have skipped significant steps here.

Comment: That's the only info I have, because as I said, everything seems to be running half smoothly. I know GC stops because once it reached up to more than 400K threads, meaning about hours without even doing a single clean on threads that should have already be removed. Me and two other developers tested lots of possibilities, like thread monitors, memory monitors and cpu monitors, nothing helped as it keeps running like that "error" didn't happen. (Sorry if this is a bit unclear)

Comment: You misunderstand the problem, this has nothing to do with GC. You create a new thread every 700ms, for a while the thread finished before the next one starts. After a while there's either more work to do per thread or the system is under more load. In any case the work takes longer than 700ms at which point threads start piling up which means lots of additional context switches, more slowdown and even more threads running.

Comment: The garbage collector does not make threads go away.  A thread goes away when its `run()` method either returns or throws an exception.  The garbage collector can make `Thread` _objects_ go away, but not until the thread that the `Thread` object controls has gone away, and not until the `Thread` object has become _unreachable_ from any other thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 16 Hours of continuous testing, the answer was a fixed ThreadPool.

Thanks to Makoto for talking about them. It seems like creating a thread manually every 700ms could crash the JVM in some way, having a fixed threadpool with a limit of threads made it go back to normal.